# webapi controller return csv data

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi controller code looks like:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadForms(FormCriteria criteria)
    {
        string downloadData = new FormsToCsvHelper(Umbraco, criteria).GetCsv();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, downloadData);
    }
```

If i look at the data returned in debugger just before sending it back it looks like:

```
Created Date,IP,Form Name,Email address,Message,Full Name
```

31/05/2019 10:43:08,127.0.0.1,Contact form - test,test12@hotmail.com,test,Ismail Mayat

If I copy and paste it into file and save as csv it looks fine in excel.

However the data i actually get back looks like:

```
"﻿Created Date,IP,Form Name,Email address,Message,Full Name\r\n31/05/2019 10:43:08,127.0.0.1,Contact form - test,test12@hotmail.com,test,Ismail Mayat"
```

The whole record set it wrapped in quote and the line feed is seen as a literal so when opening file in excel its all on one line.

There is a DelegatingHandler that fire but that is for a specific url request so for this request it does not do anything.

Anyone any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebAPI will serialize the value as JSON by default, so that's why your value is enclosed in double quotes.

To get around this, you can use the [StringContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent) class:

```cs
return new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode) {
    Content = new StringContent(downloadData, Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv")
};
```